Reissuing an accesstoken using a refresh token in react, apollor graphql

This is a query statement that retrieves user information. If error 401 occurs here

import { ApolloError, gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

interface IUserInfo {
  fetchUser: {
    picture: string;
    nickname: string;
    email: string;
  };
}
const GET_USER = gql`
  query {
    fetchUser {
      picture
      nickname
      email
    }
  }
`;

const useUser = () => {
  const { data, error, loading, refetch } = useQuery<IUserInfo>(GET_USER, {
    onError(error) {},
  });

  return {
    user: data?.fetchUser,
    error: error?.graphQLErrors[0]?.originalError,
    loading,
  };
};

export default useUser;



This is where you send the request to the server.

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloError,
  ApolloLink,
  ApolloProvider,
  InMemoryCache,
  Observable,
  createHttpLink,
  fromPromise,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { RESTORE_TOKEN_MUTATION } from './graphql/mutations/restore-token-mutation';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const restoreAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await client.mutate({
      mutation: RESTORE_TOKEN_MUTATION,
    });
    console.log('Token refreshed:', response);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Token refresh error:', error);
    throw new ApolloError({
      graphQLErrors: [error],
      networkError: error,
    });
  }
};




const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
      if (err.message === 'Unauthorized') {
        return fromPromise(
          restoreAccessToken()
            .then((token) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', token);

              const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
              operation.setContext({
                headers: {
                  ...oldHeaders,
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              });

              return forward(operation);
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
              console.error('Refresh token error:', error);
              
              return;
            })
        ).concat(forward(operation));
      }
    }
  }
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const ApolloSetting = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

export default ApolloSetting;


But the server keeps sending 401 errors endlessly!
Here's what I expected:

When the accesstoken expires, a 401 error is thrown.

If a 401 error is received, the front desk sends a re-request to the server (via the refresh token in the header)

The server receives the refresh token stored in headers.cookie and issues and sends a new accessToken if the validity period remains.

If req.headers.cookie does not exist or refresh token authentication fails, an error is sent again.


This is what I expected.
How can I escape infinite error?
My server is nestjs + graphql.
// - resolver..

  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard('refresh'))
  @Mutation(() => String)
  restoreAccessToken(
    @Context() context: IContext, //
  ): string {
    const user = context.req.user;

    return this.authService.restoreAccessToken({ user });
  }

// - jwt

import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

export class JwtRefreshStrategies extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  'refresh',
) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: (req) => {
        let refreshToken = null;
        if (req && req.headers.cookie) {
          const cookie = req.headers.cookie;
          console.log('cookie:', cookie);
          const cookieParts = cookie.split(';').map((c) => c.trim());
          const refreshTokenCookie = cookieParts.find((c) =>
            c.startsWith('refreshToken='),
          );
          if (refreshTokenCookie) {
            refreshToken = refreshTokenCookie.substring('refreshToken='.length);
          }
        }

        return refreshToken;
      },
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_REFRESH_KEY, // secretKey
    });
  }

  validate(payload) {
    console.log('payload::', payload);

    return {
      id: payload.sub,
    };
  }
}


